# How to omit changes from merge?

Tags: git, version-control

I just started using git (git svn) and imported SVN repo.

What I'm trying to achieve:

I would like to have 2 branches where branch A would have a project, branch A_dev would have the same project, but with tweaked configuration that would allow me to test my code. So my development would happen in A_dev and then I would merge my changes to A (all but the configuration changes).

Is there a way I could have my configuration changes to A_dev ignored my further merges of this branch to A?

So far I tried using

```
git merge -s ours <rev> A_dev
```

where rev is revision where changes to configuration were committed to A_dev, which works fine until I run

```
git svn rebase
```

after which the configuration changes get applied to A.

Other than that what I could think of is to have configuration changes only in stash and apply each time I checkout A_dev, which is kind of annoying. Or maybe do it the other way around and develop on A and then merge to A_dev, test switch to A fix problem, which is also not quite it.

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is saved in an isolated file, you may ignore this file (those files). See ".gitignore" file in the documentation for details or for example [this site](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html)

Comment: Those files are already tracked and are present in svn repository, but the solution I found just now is to use git update-index --assume-unchanged file